# I want to learn how to make customize xpath for selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I want to learn how to make customize xpath 
I tried this

```
//*[@class='btn btn-primary goliveBtn btn-lg float-right']//*[@text()="Go Live"]
```

but its not working

Comment: Share your HTML code.

Comment: <button _ngcontent-c10="" class="btn btn-primary goliveBtn btn-lg float-right">Go Live </button>

Comment: i knw you can make for me but i want to learn by my own so is there any formula for making customize xpath

Comment: There’s not any formula, only one way that is you should learn it. No other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your point.You are probably looking after this.

```
//*[@class='btn btn-primary goliveBtn btn-lg float-right'][contains(.,"Go Live")]
```

OR use `normalize-space`

```
//*[@class='btn btn-primary goliveBtn btn-lg float-right'][normalize-space(text())='Go Live']
```

Comment: ok is this standard method i can use it with others xpath also??

Comment: <input _ngcontent-c21="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="projectName" name="projectName" required="" type="text" placeholder="Enter value...">

Comment: //*[@class='form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched'][normalize-space(id())='projectName']

Comment: Instead of normalize-space use [@id=‘projectName’]

Comment: Instead of normalize-space use [@id=‘projectName’]

Comment: @ArjunBharadwaj : Try the following xpath : `//input[@class='form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched'][@id='projectName']`

Answer (score 0):

you are using multiple attributes,if u want to use multiple attributes you can go for above one but you didn't mention tag for both elements, use tag *(any tag)

//*[@class='btn btn-primary goliveBtn btn-lg float-right']//*[@text()="Go Live"]

if it is single element to inpect thenuse below

//*[@class='btn btn-primary goliveBtn btn-lg float-right' and  @text()="Go Live"]

Comment: post your html dom with 10 lines for which element you have to inspect.